# How to access to array values on an Php Object

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object 
( 
    [string] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => EXL 
        [1] => TEMPS 
    ) 
)


stdClass Object 
( 
   [string] => IP
)
```

How to access to EXL, TEMPS and IP values with a loop for ?

Comment: try something like `$array->string->{0}`

Comment: `$array->string[0]` this will get EXL

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the parent array as Object, but the child's are normal array.

SO try this.

```
$array->string[0];  //get the EXL
```

**Example:**

```
$array = array(
    "string" => array("EXL", "TEMPS"),
    "string2" => array("EXL 2", "TEMPS 2"),
);

$obj_arr = (Object) $array;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj_arr);
echo "</pre>";

echo $obj_arr->string[0]."<br/>".$obj_arr->string[1];
```

**Output:**

> EXL
>   TEMPS

Comment: `for on the array` means??

Answer (score 0):

> In your case, this is an instance of a Class which gives you an Object.

**There are two commonly used methods to target an Array within an Object:**

```
// Loop through each stored data
foreach($Object->string as $_string)
{
    echo $_string;
}
```

**Or you can access the Array directly:**

```
echo $Object->string[0];
```

The `->` in PHP is how we use Objects (map).

Both work fine.

> EDIT: Reading comments

**To access the Array held in the Object within a `for` loop:**

```
// $i starts at 0 since array index's start at 0
for($i = 0; $i < count($Obj->string); $i++)
{
    echo $Obj->string[$i];
    // TODO: Add your code...
}
```

Comment: `echo $Object->string->{0}; // Just looks cleaner (IMO)` wrong 0 is an array index not a property. `echo $Obj->string->{$i};` same as before it's an array index.

Comment: He didn't state any of what you're saying above, if it hassles you, edit it.

Comment: OP doesn't have to state that if everything is in the output. *if it hassles me* , you posted an answer here and I just point out what is technical incorrect at your answer.